# HIde taxonomy menu based on count? Possibly using rules?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Is it possible to hide taxonomy menu items based on their node count?

E.g. i have several zounds categories (notebooks, office, health, etc) created but they are just empty taxonomy items because the client has yet to add these products.

I'd like only the taxonomy terms with nodes to be visible.

Is it possible to accomplish this via rules or some other module?

**Background:**

I have a taxonomy menu created by [taxonomy_menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) and then it's turned into a [menu block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) and that menu block is turn into a [superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish) dropdown menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option in the [taxonomy_menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) "Hide empty items" to disable menu options if there are no nodes tagged with the specific term. The option can be found in the **admin/structure/taxonomy** then the vacab you are using.

Below is an image for reference.

[Settings Image](http://drupal.org/files/issues/Screen%20shot%202011-03-18%20at%206.20.01%20PM.png)